# Does Azure Function App require a globally unique name?

Tags: azure, function

With my limited experience on Azure cloud, I am having the impression that Azure Function App requires a globally unique name. It seems true that if you test creating a new Function App through Azure Portal.
However, I have seen in a recent project that same function app (with same name) with different settings of course, being deployed to multiple resource groups under same subscription.

Can anyone explain? I am struggling to find an official answer from Microsoft sites.
Many thanks,
W

Answer (score 5):

You are right, Azure function app name must have Globally unique name.

When you create Azure function app, you specify the name which becomes part of URL `<azurefunctionname>.azurewebsites.net`

Valid characters for Azure function app name are a-z (case insensitive), 0-9, and -.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal#create-a-function-app